# Angularjs getting circular dependency even using association binder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm getting this error in my AngularJS app using ng-repeat:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
```

I create an [name]_association_binder.js to make the relationships between the 2 entities, in this case is the: https://github.com/WagnerMoreira/test-poc/blob/master/app/javascripts/services/transducers/transducer_association_binder.js#L18

So this should works, I have "A" that depends on "B" and vice-versa, but I have an "C" that is my association_binder.js that make the relations, if you have any idea about this just tell me =D

my controller: https://github.com/WagnerMoreira/test-poc/blob/master/app/javascripts/controllers/transducer_details_controller.js

The line where I'm calling the ng-repeat: https://github.com/WagnerMoreira/test-poc/blob/master/public/index.html#L186

If you wanna test just clone this repo and open the index.html in browser, no server is needed.
Then click on transducers menu, click in one item in the grid and then "exames" tab, you'll get this error in console.